# Rabbitmq, IModel memory leak. c# .net framework

Tags: c#, memory, rabbitmq

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    HostName = "localhost",
    UserName = "guest",
    Password = "guest",
    VirtualHost = "/",
    RequestedHeartbeat = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10),
    AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
    TopologyRecoveryEnabled = true,
    NetworkRecoveryInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500),
};
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        var arguments = new Dictionary<String, Object>
                        {
                            {"x-message-ttl", 60000},
                            {"x-max-length", 5000}
                        };


        string exchangename = "oleg_exchange";
        string queuename = "oleg_queue";
        channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangename, "direct", true, false, arguments);
        channel.QueueDeclare(queuename, true, false, true, arguments);
        channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
        channel.QueueBind(queuename, exchangename, "receipt", arguments);
    }
}
```

[memory dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjjl2.png)
Here you can see that exactly 5000 objects were created AutorecoveringModel, although objects must be destroyed.

But if you close the connection, then everything is cleared.

```
connection.Close();
```

This is normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
channel.QueueBind(queuename, exchangename, "receipt", arguments);
```

no need to add arguments here.
although this is rather a bug in rabbitmq.
If you remove the arguments from here, there will be no memory leak

```
channel.QueueBind(queuename, exchangename, "receipt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , that is not a memory leak , as you are creating multiple Channels , each channel is individually managed in the memory . As per the guidelines it is however not recommended to open multiple channels and there is no need to open channel per operation. Would suggest to revisit the code as per the use case.

Comment: What happens if I need to process 1,000,000 requests? As far as I know, it is not necessary to reuse channels. You can reuse channels only in the newest versions rabbitmq, because the channels are thread-safe there, but not in the earlier versions.